# Изменение отображения страницы без перезагрузки

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Ситуация такова. При уменьшении / увеличении размера окна браузера выполняется определённый jquery код, который изменяет высоту некоторых элементов. Но проблема в том, что применяются эти изменения лишь после перезагрузки страницы и только после заветной F5 всё смотрится нормально. Возможно ли как-то сделать что бы всё этоизменялось в "лайв" режиме?

Вот та самая страница : https://03oziged.github.io/man/

Comment: Вопросы надо править, а не плодить одинаковые...

Comment: Создайте в предыдущем вопросе работающий пример, который демонстрирует описываемое Вами поведение.

Comment: Евгений, под вопросом есть кнопка `править`, надо ее нажать и переформулировать, если есть мнения, что вопрос не поняли и ответ не отвечает на вопрос. А не плодить одинаковые

Answer (score 1):

По итогу нашёл решение в виде jqury плагина, который уравнивает высоту элементов, как мне и требовалось.
https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height#install

Answer (score 0):

Вы ошибаетесь, думая, что изменения размеров элементов происходят при изменении размеров окна. Поместите код, который вычисляет и назначает эти размеры в

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  // ... сюда
});
```

---

По поводу манеры оформления вопроса. Вы ошибаетесь, считая, что здесь найдется много желающих идти на какой-то сторонний ресурс и разбираться в Вашем минимизированном коде.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНовиков "window resize ситуации не изменил" - джентльменам верят на слово? Создайте в вопросе работающий пример.

Answer (score 0):

Igor, подложил использовать `window reszie` и я его поддерживаю.

Сделайте следующее:
Возьмите весь код выполняющийся при загрузке страницы, естественно тот, который относится к изменению дизайна, и засуньте его в отдельную функцию, а дальше так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  YouFunction();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
  YouFunction();
});
```